# How to set completionThreshold to AutoCompleteTextView with java code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, autocompletetextview, layoutparams

I have this AutoCompleteTextView:

```
AutoCompleteTextView a = new AutoCompleteTextView(this);
```

I need to set completionThreshold flag value to 1, and i want to learn doing it with java code. I searched on google and stackoverflow and i didn't found the way.

I just need to do this:  `android:completionThreshold="1"` with java code.

How can this be done?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold(int)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use setThreshold(int) method

for more info [setThreshold](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can also add following line in corresponding XML file:

```
android:completionThreshold="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Above code will set the completion threshold to 1 programmatically.

```
       survey.setThreshold(1);
```